# Time Syncronization via Web Service Call

Tags: web-services, time, synchronization, ntp

Say are dealing with a Windows network that for internet access must pass through a firewall that you have no control over. Said firewall apparently blocks the known time protocols (NTP,daytime,etc) and you know from experience that those who control
it will not allow any exceptions.

Is it possible to sync this "Windows" (could be linux) computer via a web service call which grabs the time from a server out on the internet?

Is there another reliable method for updating time on the server, like pulling from a website and passing it to the ntp client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP Time Protocol:

http://www.vervest.org/fiki/bin/view/HTP/WebHome

It takes the date from the http server itself, not from a website served by it

Comment: URL is dead.  Any current reference?